# MySQL - Private Posts Display Correct Count

Tags: mysql, count

So I have 4 tables: users, posts, private, threads. In this example, lizzy created 2 private posts in different threads:

'Dating' post is for users 2,5,6 and herself to see the correct count of posts in that thread.

'Break Ups' post is for user 2 only and herself to see the correct count of posts in that thread.

Displaying the correct count depending on the user viewing the thread is the issue I am having. Here, we are focusing on lizzy, her threads, and post counts:

```
users                     (These aren't part of table. Just shows the counts we should display with our query depending on the user_id)
user_id |  user_name      //thread #: post_count-post_count_if_not_authorized = count to show 
--------------------
   1    |    tony         //thread 2: 3-1= 2 posts. thread 3: 2-1= 1 post.
   2    |    steph        //thread 2: 3-0= 3 posts. thread 3: 2-0= 2 posts.
   3    |    lizzy        //thread 2: 3 posts. thread 3: 2 posts.
   4    |    adam         //thread 2: 3-1= 2 posts. thread 3: 2-1= 1 post.
   5    |    lara         //thread 2: 3-0= 3 posts. thread 3: 2-1= 1 post.
   6    |    alexa        //thread 2: 3-0= 3 posts. thread 3: 2-1= 1 post.


posts
post_id   thread_id   user_id   post_name   private (0 is public, 1 is private to authorized users)
-----------------------------------------------------
   1         1           1       Coding        0
   2         2           3       Dating        1
   3         2           3       Show Me       0
   4         2           3       See Me        0 
   5         3           3       Break Ups     1
   6         3           3       True Love     0

private
private_id   post_id   authorized_user_id
-----------------------------------------------
    1           2               2
    2           2               5
    3           2               6
    4           5               2

threads
thread_id  user_id  post_count
------------------------------------
    1         1         1
    2         3         3  | When outputted in php, we should subtract the correct COUNT
    3         3         2  | from this depending on the user viewing the thread like above.
```

So basically, we have a total thread count with all posts in that thread. But if we pull that out with a mysql query, all users will see all lizzy's post_count for each thread she has, when instead, only lizzy and any users she authorized to view certain posts on a thread should see the correct visible non private count for them. What would be the most efficient way to pull out the counts as a row (post_count_if_not_authorized) so we can subtract it from the post_count to show each user the correct count for them only?

Something like the below is what I am after (not working of course as is):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.thread_id, t.post_count, t.COUNT(*)
FROM threads as t
JOIN posts as p on p.user_id = t.user_id
LEFT JOIN private pv on pv.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE t.user_id='3'
    AND (p.private = 0) OR (pv.authorized_user_id = {$logged_in_id} and p.private = 1)
```

**UPDATE:**

(t.user_id='3' in the WHERE clause is for lizzy in this example, and if $logged_in_id should give the correct count depending on the user, like the counts in the user table above)

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51286/7).

The output should look like this if tony ($logged_in_id=1) is viewing lizzy's (user_id=3) started threads:

```
thread_id    post_count_final (this should have the correct count for this user($logged_in_id) to see, all posts by lizzy - private posts by lizzy that this user is not authorized to see)
    2            2
    3            1
```

If steph ($logged_in_id=2) is viewing lizzy's (user_id=3) started threads:

```
thread_id    post_count_final (this should have the correct count for this user($logged_in_id) to see, all posts by lizzy - private posts by lizzy that this user is not authorized to see)
    2            3
    3            2
```

(Note: The top right part next to the users table shows how these numbers are derived.)

Comment: Can you explain you users table data?

Comment: It's better formatted now, just a user_id and user_name

Comment: For clarity, can you add the desired result to your post above.

Comment: @Strawberry Added an output section showing the desired result for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
t.thread_id, t.post_count, 
COUNT(IF(ISNULL(pv.private_id) AND p.private='1' AND p.user_id<>'1', null, 1)) 
FROM threads as t
JOIN posts as p on p.thread_id = t.thread_id 
JOIN users as u on u.user_id = p.user_id 
LEFT JOIN private as pv on pv.post_id = p.post_id AND pv.authorized_user_id='1' 
JOIN users as auth on auth.user_id = '1'
WHERE p.user_id='3' AND t.user_id='3'
GROUP BY t.thread_id;
```

This should work even if lizzy (logged in) is viewing lizzy. Adding COUNT(*) would return the same value as t.post_count. You could completely eliminate the use of threads table and do the counting in query all together, although the query will be more heavy.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have three questions regarding your answer: 1. Can you please explain "COUNT(IF(ISNULL(pv.private_id) AND p.private<>'0' AND p.user_id<>'1', null, 1))" in detail? It seems to work but I can't figure out what all the parts do/mean. 2. If we use $logged_in_id as 7, which doesn't exist. We still get results. Does this make sense? Also, what if a user is logged out, so $logged_in_id='', would the query be the same? 3.If not using the threads table, I feel the counting will be too heavy on each page reload. Do you suggest this as the most efficient solution?

Comment: **1.** **COUNT()** will count records where the content of the function is not null. That is what the **IF(,null,1)** is for.
**2.** Added af join to users as 'auth' to do authentication. This will return 0 records if user not logged in (both '7' and '')
**3.** Yes I agree if the number of posts will be become large over time, then I would prefer maintaining a count rather than query it every time.

Comment: For easier readability and logic I turned the IF into a CASE like this: COUNT(case when ISNULL(pv.private_id) AND p.private='1' AND p.user_id='3' then null else 1 end) Is this correct? Instead of p.private<>'0', and p.user_id<>'1' (as there will be more than users 1 & 3), I put the above p.private='1', and p.user_id='3'. Also, why would it mess up the count id we put 0 instead of null in the then else?

Comment: I tested and my changes work but one final issue with it. If I am logged in as lizzy $logged_in_id='3', is there a way to skip the count operation completely in the sql statement, and return a custom value such as 'threadder' for the row? Something like: COUNT(if(p.user_id<>'3' then 'threadder' else (case when ISNULL(pv.private_id) AND p.private='1' AND p.user_id='3' then null else 1 end)) as custom_count_row

Comment: Replacing with CASE is fine, however the last condition has to be **p.user_id <> {$logged_in_id}** to prevent counting it if the user is not the poster. The way COUNT() works can be a little confusing, whether the content is 0, 1, 100 or false does not matter it will still count the record, only if the content is null will it be excluded.

Comment: As for skipping I guess you could do something like `IF(p.user_id={$logged_in_id},  
   'threader', 
   COUNT(case when ISNULL(pv.private_id) AND p.private='1' AND p.user_id<>{$logged_in_id} then null else 1 end)
)` but wouldn't that just return _'threader'_ for all records, when lizzy is viewing lizzy?

Comment: This part confuses me: p.user_id<>{$logged_in_id}, I put it as p.user_id='3', where 3 is thread originator, if we are looking at lizzy's. If we are lizzy, I'm trying to just use the post_count as is from the threads table and completely skip over the count so it doesn't need to count anything for lizzy. I'm thinking if we return 'threader' instead of the count row, in php when we analyze the row, if 'threadder' is returned, we display the post_count without any counting. If threadder is not returned, then we display the numeric count as count will run in that instance. Is p.user_id='3' wrong?

Comment: Yes **p.user_id='3'** is wrong because this would always evaluate to _true_ since this criteria is already stated in the _WHERE_ part of the query. The only purpose of **p.user_id={$logged_in_id}** is to make sure that, when lizzy is logged in she will see her own posts, even if these posts are private and she no specific authentication in the _'private'_ table. Try run your version and query lizzys posts logged in as lizzy. That will return 2,1 instead of 3,2.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it all makes sense now, first bounty awarded:)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the proper `group by` syntax, does it work?

```
SELECT t.thread_id, t.post_count, COUNT(*)
FROM threads as t
JOIN posts as p on p.user_id=t.user_id 
LEFT JOIN private pv on pv.post_id=p.post_id
WHERE (p.private=0) OR (pv.authorized_user_id={$logged_in_id} and p.private=1) 
group by t.thread_id, t.post_count
```